# "javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated"

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

Am trying to communicate between BiZConnect gateway to one of my client gateway. i have installed SSL certificate at my end ans also shared the public key with trade partner.

I am getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated"  error while sending the file to my https client partner.

i checked with my internal system engineer and confirmed port 443 and 80 is open at network level. can you please help me if i have to check anything in protocol level to establish the connection successfully?

How do i check my SSL certificate is valid to communicate with https client.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You either didn't ask for a client certificate or you didn't get one. It has nothing whatsoever to do with ports 80 or 443.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this. Client Certificate you mean the certificate which i have got from my Trading Partner?

Comment: I mean the certificate which you *didn't* get from the peer.